# How to configure jest tests with MERN stack?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, jestjs, mern

I'm trying to understand why jest tests raise an errors, here is my code:
monogodb connection:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb')
MongoClient.connect(
    process.env.MONGODB_URL,
    {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    },
    async (error, client) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Unable to connect')
            throw error
        }
        console.log('MongoDB is connected!')

        //Global variable defined and will be reached by all scripts (routers) of App.js in server
        global.db = client.db(process.env.DATABASE_NAME)
    }
)
```

example of test script which cause a problem (there are another):

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
const request = require('supertest')
const app = require('../server/app-source')

test('Signup as a current user, so it will return 409 status code', async () => {
    await request(app)
        .post('/sign-up')
        .send({
            username: 'test user',
            password: 'test password',
            confirmPass: 'test password',
            email: 'test@test.com',
            role: 'Customer',
        })
        .expect(409)
})

test('Access the homepage as a user (test user which created above)', async () => {
    await request(app)
        .post('/login')
        .send({
            username: 'test user',
            password: 'test password',
        })
        .expect(200)
})

test('Access the homepage as non-user', async () => {
    await request(app)
        .post('/login')
        .send({
            username: 'non-test user',
            password: 'non-test password',
        })
        .expect(404)
})
```

I'm receiving the following errors: **Cannot read property 'JSON' of null** and **ReferenceError: db is not defined**.
both of the errors printed in catch block inside the router http requests functions (in backend).
The tests was passed when i connect to database in every request but it caused a lot of delays so I changed it to this format in which I defined the 'db' variable as global and connect to database only once.
It's important to note that the client-server communication is working perfectly in the website himself, those errors has been raised only in Jest tests.
Thanks for helpers!